# How to track an object during animation?

Tags: javafx

I am making a tower defense game. The user places a tower and there is a thread that pools the tower to see if there are any monsters near by. Right now I am working on animating the path using a simple rectangle to test things. The [Path](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/animations/basics.htm#CJAFADFJ) is easy to work with and is go to choice, but unlike the Timeline I can not gather the coordinates relative to where the shape is.

I have had success detecting the rectangle position using  the Timeline class with Keyframes but I can not create the paths using multiple keyframes and get the visual effects I want.

The Path class gives me the visual effects I want, but seems to have no way of tracking the shape.

Is there a way I can either track the location of the shape along the path, or is there a way to make the same style path using the Timeline class. Also is there an easier API I am missing here?

```
    rectBasicTimeline = new Rectangle (0, 0, 40, 40);
    monsterLayer.getChildren().add(rectBasicTimeline);

    //gets coordinates of rectangle and see if tower is in range
    TowerAttackerService testService = new TowerAttackerService();
    testService.start();

    Path path = new Path();
    boolean isFirst = true;

    //gathers path coordinates from search algorithm
    for(Coordinate coords : pathCoords){
        if(isFirst){
            path.getElements().add(new MoveTo(coords.getExactX(),coords.getExactY()));
            isFirst = false;
        }
        else{
            path.getElements().add(new LineTo(coords.getExactX(),coords.getExactY()));
        }
    }

    PathTransition pathTransition = new PathTransition();
    pathTransition.setDuration(Duration.millis(10000));
    pathTransition.setPath(path);
    pathTransition.setNode(rectBasicTimeline);
    pathTransition.play();
```

To get the rectangle location I have been calling the getX() and getY() method which returns 0.0

Comment: Take a look at [AnimationTimerTest.java](https://gist.github.com/james-d/8327842), which is a collision detection system based upon an animation timer and then edit your question to summarize your current thoughts based upon your additional research.

Comment: Will do! Thanks for the link